# Mocking file system for unit testing file watcher library

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am currently unit testing a wrapper I've written around [Chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar), which is a file system watcher, which is itself a wrapper around native fs.watch functionality. I write my tests with mocha/chai.

I know there is this wonderful library [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs), the caveat however is that it says at the bottom

> The following fs functions are not currently mocked (if your tests use these, they will work against the real file system): fs.FSWatcher, fs.unwatchFile, fs.watch, and fs.watchFile. Pull requests welcome.

So it will not help me unit testing my watcher.

Currently I have it set up with true read/writes to the fs, without mocking, but it's tedious and timing dependent (which makes it hardware dependent).

Would anybody be able to advise me on perhaps better approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem earlier today. There is another library for mocking  node fs called [fs-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-mock) . This library allows you to mock fs.watch() . You can do the following  :

```
const Fs = require("fs-mock")        
const fsmock = new Fs({
      './mock-directory': {
        'file9.txt': 'fileContent9',
        'file8.txt': 'fileContent8',
        'file7.txt': 'fileContent7',
        'file6.txt': 'fileContent6',
        'file5.txt': 'fileContent5',
        'file4.txt': 'fileContent4',
        'file3.txt': 'fileContent3',
        'file2.txt': 'fileContent2',
      }
    })

fsmock.watch(directory, { recursive: false },
    (eventType, filename) => {
                  //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
       })
```

Comment: fs.watch is not supported by fs-mock: https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/246